# Special characters are not passing through as payload in mule

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have following json that I am using as a #[payload] in mule but the special characters are getting converted into ?? in Request body.

```
{
  "AcceptTruliooTermsAndConditions": true,
  "CleansedAddress": false,
  "VerboseMode": true,
  "ConfigurationName": "Identity Verification",
  "CountryCode": "CN",
  "DataFields": {
    "PersonInfo": {
      "FirstGivenName": "言明",
      "FirstSurName": "胡",
      "DayOfBirth": 5,
      "MonthOfBirth": 6,
      "YearOfBirth": 1976
    },
    "NationalIds": [
      {
        "Number": "440861896421345987",
        "Type": "NationalID"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Because of this I am not getting the correct output.

Comment: What is the encoding of the payload?